# Unable to debug the Custom Receiver Application of Chromecast

Tags: chromecast

I've downloaded Chrome cast sender and receiver application from GitHub. While running the application I am getting some error on my device as well as sender application. I want to debug the Receiver Application. I've followed all the guidelines mentioned on this link [https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver#debugging ] but unable to even open the debug window using the mentioned URL.
Please suggest me something that I need to check to get it debugged as I am new to chrome cast.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your own application id (by registering your app in Cast Developer Console). Follow the instructions for [registration](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration) and in that same page, scroll down to Devices and follow those steps as well. After all of that, give it a bit of time, reboot your chromecast and it should work when your app is running on the chromecast.

Comment: I have registered my own application id on the Cast Developer Console. And also registered my device. But still not able to get the logs. Chromecast and the machine on which i am trying to get the logs are on same wifi network. Is it necessary for the server [where i've hosted the receiver application] to be on the same network or it can be on different network?

Comment: Yes, they should be on the same network; make sure you are running your receiver app when trying to connect using the debugger.

Comment: Any suggestions for finding my Chromecast IP address as specified in the OP's link to the Google instructions?  Can't find it via the Setup App at all, or anywhere else for that matter.  Thanks!

Comment: If you use the Chromecast Application (the one you use to set up chromecast), it should have the IP address, at least on iOS and Android (I haven't recently checked the Chrome one but I suspect that has that too); select the device and then when it shows the details of the device, scroll down and toward the bottom you should see the IP address.